# Adding a single variable sorted in ascending order in R

Tags: r, variables, sequence

Suppose I have a dataset(`mydata`) and want to add a new column (`newvar`):

```
newvar <- c(11, 5, 6, 7, 3, 12, 4, 5, 9)

mydata$newvar <- newvar
```

How can I add a new column with values that are strictly increasing from 1 to 3 million?

Of course I cannot write something like:

```
newvar <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ..., 3000000)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
newvar <- 1:3000000
mydata$newvar <- newvar
```

Answer (score 2):

Let's review the methods to create a sequence in R.

```
### Method 1
newvar1 <- 1:3000000
##3 Method 2
newvar2 <- seq(1, 3000000, by = 1)
### Method 3
newvar3 <- seq(1L, 3000000L)
### Method 4
newvar4 <- seq.int(1L, 3000000L)
### method 5
newvar5 <- seq_len(3000000)
### Method 6
# Create example data frame
mydata <- data.frame(Var = runif(3000000))

newvar6 <- seq_along(mydata$Var)
```

Method 1 uses `:` to create the sequence. Method 2 and Method 3 use `seq` to specify the `from` and `to` of a sequence. Notice that the output of Method 2 is `numeric`, while the Method 3 is `integer`, indicating the way to specify the `from` and `to` is important to the class type of the output.

Method 4 uses `seq.int`. Method 5 uses `seq_len` with specifying the `length.out` argument, which is a number showing the length of the sequence Method 6 uses the `seq_along` with specifying the `along.with` argument, which is a vector with the same length of the desired output. This means that we can specify `along.with` as the same as one of the columns in the targeted data frame.

I used the `microbenchmark` package to compare the speed of these methods. Keep in mind that among these method, the output of Method 2 is `numeric`, while all the others are `integer`.

```
library(microbenchmark)   
library(ggplot2)

m <-microbenchmark(m1 = {1:3000000},
                   m2 = {seq(1, 3000000, by = 1)},
                   m3 = {seq(1L, 3000000L)},
                   m4 = {seq.int(1L, 3000000L)},
                   m5 = {seq_len(3000000)},
                   m6 = {seq_along(mydata$Var)},
                   times = 1000)
m
# Unit: milliseconds
# expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq      max neval
#   m1  3.646180  3.902131  7.614828  4.121517  4.825223 202.5163  1000
#   m2 39.496001 44.544780 59.336825 52.322098 59.685341 291.0407  1000
#   m3  3.701989  3.978467  7.353326  4.181496  4.832920 154.9543  1000
#   m4  3.675046  3.938375  7.085586  4.132423  4.670625 166.1905  1000
#   m5  3.674405  3.928431  7.744393  4.129857  4.793149 153.2762  1000
#   m6  3.724440  3.959223  7.021631  4.192081  4.810148 158.8564  1000

autoplot(m)
```

[image]

The results show that Method 2 is a lot slower than the other methods, but no significant difference were observed for other methods.

Comment: Amazing that such a basic question can generate such a useful answer!

Comment: @ClausWilke Thanks. And Thanks for the OP to let me have this chance to review these different methods.

Answer (score 1):

You should do:

```
newvar <- seq(1, 3000000, 1)
```

Comment: Actually, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47739867/4975218) shows that that's the one thing that shouldn't be done in this case.